# How to set the order of validation methods ruby on rails？

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am a Ror beginner. There is a model **Lectur**e, I want to validate the format of start time and end time firstly, and then check if the end time is after start time. It works well when the format is valid but once the format is wrong it comes with: undefined method `<' for nil:NilClass. How to makes *start_must_be_before_end_time*  triggered only when the format is valid? Thanks!

Here is the code:

```
class Lecture < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :day
belongs_to :speaker
validates :title, :position, presence: true



validates :start_time, format: { with: /([01][0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9])/,
         message: "Incorrect time format" }


validates :end_time, format: { with: /([01][0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9])/,
        message: "Incorrect time format" }


validate :start_must_be_before_end_time

private
def start_must_be_before_end_time
    errors.add(:end_time, "is before Start time") unless start_time < end_time
end

end
```

Comment: Is a lecture record valid without a `start_time` or `end_time`? If not, you should add the check for the presence of them, like `if start_time.present?`, before comparing them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no guarantees on the order of validations that are defined by `validates` methods. But, the order is guaranteed for [custom validators](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-methods) that are defined with `validate` method.

From docs:

> You can pass more than one symbol for each class method and the respective validations will be **run in the same order as they were registered**.

#### Alternatively

You can only run your validation method if all other validations pass:

```
validate :start_must_be_before_end_time, :unless => Proc.new { |obj| obj.times_valid? }

# Then, define `times_valid?` method and check that start_time and end_time are valid
```

Comment: I tried the proc method and write the times_valid? method: return true when both start and end time is in right method. But when I input wrong format like 88:88 or 9999, this still says  undefined method `<' for nil:NilClass. I do not know what is wrong.

Comment: I solve this problem with:   validate :start_must_be_before_end_time, :unless => Proc.new { |a| a.errors[:start_time].any? || a.errors[:end_time].any?        there must some mistakes I cannot find when I apply your method, but it is similar. Anyway, thank you!

Answer (score -1):

You can go another way:

```
errors.add(:end_time, "is before Start time") unless start_time.nil? || end_time.nil? || start_time < end_time
```